# Handle Listview insert duplicate sql error ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, sql-server-2012

This is my first time asking a question and I've been searching for 2 days to find an answer. Hopefully one of you masters can assist.

I have a 4 column listview populated from a sql table. The table doesn't allow duplicates. I simply want to be able to catch that error and give a friendly message to the user that the item is already in the list. I have found multiple solutions that don't work (probably my error).

Below is the one that I had the most hope for... but nothing.

Still getting "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tbl.associateNames'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl.associateNames'.
The statement has been terminated"

```
   Protected Sub listviewInserting_itemInserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewInsertEventArgs)


    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=server\instance; Initial Catalog=sears;User Id=johnnyFive;Password=alive;"
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [tbl.associateNames] ([orderIssuer], [associateName], [department]) VALUES (@orderIssuer, @associateName, @department)"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox("Duplicate Entry found", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Dups")
        e.Cancel = True
    End Try

End Sub
```

ANY suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Should work. Perhaps the wrong type of execption? What happens if you enlarge the catch to

```
Catch ex As Exception
```

Comment: Thanks but still no luck. Still getting the ugly error.

Answer (score 0):

I am officially an idiot.

Had I remembered to put this line like this (i.e. add the Handles blah blah) I wouldn't have had the issue.

```
Protected Sub listviewInserting_itemInserted(ByVal sender As Object, e As ListViewInsertEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemInserting

    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
```